# Correlation between network throughput and number of concurrent users

Tags: lan, throughput

I need to identify/formulate the relationship between number of concurrent users that are downloading data from a server on network throughput. Suppose, we have a 600KB file on a server A and N users download it at the same time. So, I would lie to know that how increase in N impacts of network throughput.

Is the relation linear? any equation for

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions to be made here on the type of network media, bandwidth, server throughput, etc.   But when you say impact on network throughput, do you mean throughput for each of the users?  Or do you mean network utilization?

Comment: By throughput, I mean the time each of N user should wait to get data from server.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me make up some numbers:

Assume a network bandwidth of 4.8Mbps. That works out to 600kB/sec, ignoring overhead.

So one user would get the file in 1 sec (again, ignoring overhead). 2 users would take 2 sec and so on.

Answer (score 0):

User Waiting time:

If you are interested in the mean time (T) each of N user should wait for the data, you can model the system as an M/G/1 queue. T can be seen as "waiting in queue" +  "service time". For the latter you can assume deterministic service time (is the time for serving one only user), and for the former you can use the M/G/1 formula for queueing time ( M is for exponential distributed arrival that is good if user are uncorrelated; G is for geneneral service time, and in this case you can assume deterministic service time, e.g the time for serving a single user, and 1 stands for only one server aviable).

mean queueing time M/G/1: (l*(mean service time)^2) / 2(1 - ro))

where:

l (arrival/sec) is the arrival intensity: it is the parameter for exponential distribution modelling the arrival

ro= l*(mean service time)

Server working time:
if you are interested in the time that is need for the server for finishing the job:
assuming F the file dimension, N the number of user, and C the server throughput, the server has to transmit NF bits. The time needed is NF/C